# abort() calling pointer array error

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

```
int main(){

vector <string> v;

std::ifstream input("data.txt");
std::string line;
```

reading data from a text file
file contain rows of data each row contain 1 argument 4 rows collectively make a student data

```
while( std::getline( input, line ) ) {
    v.push_back(line);
}
int k = 0, count = 0;
int size = v.size() / 4;
Student **temp;
temp = new Student*[size];
string name, ID, department, CGPA;
```

here i am reading vector and creating a new object of student here

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size();++i)
{
    if (k == 0)
    {
        name = v[i];
    }
    if (k == 1)
    {
        ID = v[i];
    }
    if (k == 2)
    {
        department = v[i];
    }
    if (k == 3)
    {
        CGPA = v[i];
        k = 0;
```

here it get crashed

```
        temp[count] = new Student(name, stof(ID.c_str()), department, stof(CGPA.c_str()));
        temp[count]->print();
        count++;
        //cout << name << "\t" << ID << "\t" << department << "\t" << CGPA << endl;
        //break;
    }
    k++;

}

system("pause");

 }
```

Comment: provide more details of your problem, try to upload the file example

Answer (score 2):

When `k == 3` you set `k = 0;`. Then you do `k++;`, so the next time through the loop you start with `k == 1`, and skip over the `name` assignment.

Instead of looping over `v` 1 by 1, and using a variable to keep track of which item you're processing, do it in steps of 4.

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i += 4)
{
    name = v[i];
    ID = v[i+1];
    department = v[i+2];
    CGPA = v[i+3];
    temp[count] = new Student(name, stof(ID.c_str()), department, stof(CGPA.c_str()));
    temp[count]->print();
    count++;
}
```

You could avoid all of this trouble if you just put the students into a vector. You could read the file in sets of 4 lines, create the `Student`, and then push this into the vector.

Comment: thanks man i didn't see that one comming

Comment: Don't you think you would have figured it out by using a debugger to step through the program?